# how to reset selected value of select option in shadcn ui

Tags: reactjs, select, reset, shadcnui

i want to reset value of selected after submit for select other product .

i clear state that give value from that , any input empty but select option is stay on that selected value

```
 <Select onValueChange={(value) =>
                    setSelected({ ...selected, [key]: value })
                }>
                <SelectTrigger className="w-full px-0 h-[16px] text-[13px] border-none">
                    <SelectValue placeholder={"select"} />
                </SelectTrigger>
                <SelectContent>
                    {productsList[key].map((item, index) => (
                        <SelectItem
                            key={index}
                            value={item}
                            className={`text-[12px] text-[#040714] p-1 `}
                        >
                            {item}
                        </SelectItem>
                    ))}
                </SelectContent>
            </Select>
```

```
const cancelHandler = () => {
        setSelected({});
};
```

```
                <Button
                    variant="ghost"
                    disabled={!disalbleBtns}
                    className="p-0 h-6"
                    onClick={() => submitHandler()}
                >
                    <SubmitSvg />
                </Button>
```

Answer (score -1):

you should do this :

1. use **value** and **defaultValue** together in **FormField**
2. use **form.reset(defaultValues)** after submit like this:

```
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { SubmitErrorHandler, SubmitHandler, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as z from "zod";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectItem,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
} from "@/components/ui/select";
import { toast } from "@/components/ui/use-toast";

const FormSchema = z.object({
  email: z
    .string({
      required_error: "Please select an email to display.",
    })
    .email(),
});

const defaultValues = {
  email: "",
};
export function SelectForm() {
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
    defaultValues,
  });

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>> = (data) => {
    toast({
      title: "You submitted the following values:",
      description: (
        <pre className="mt-2 w-[340px] rounded-md bg-slate-950 p-4">
          <code className="text-white">{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</code>
        </pre>
      ),
    });
    form.reset(defaultValues);
  };
  const onError: SubmitErrorHandler<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>> = (data) => {
    console.log(data, "error");
    toast({
      title: "You have error:",
      description: (
        <pre className="mt-2 w-[340px] rounded-md bg-red-700 p-4">
          {data.email?.message}
        </pre>
      ),
    });
  };

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form
        onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit, onError)}
        className="w-2/3 space-y-6"
      >
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="email"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
              <Select
                onValueChange={field.onChange}
                value={field.value}
                defaultValue={field.value}
              >
                <FormControl>
                  <SelectTrigger>
                    <SelectValue placeholder="Select a verified email to display" />
                  </SelectTrigger>
                </FormControl>
                <SelectContent>
                  <SelectItem value="m@example.com">m@example.com</SelectItem>
                  <SelectItem value="m@google.com">m@google.com</SelectItem>
                  <SelectItem value="m@support.com">m@support.com</SelectItem>
                </SelectContent>
              </Select>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
}
```